# Solve $73x-137y=0$, $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to show that the diophantine equation does only have the trivial solution $x=y=0$. Since $\text{gcd}(73,-137)=1|0$ this is solveable. So

\begin{align}
137&= 1\cdot73+64\\
73 &= 1\cdot64+9\\
64 &= 9\cdot7+1\\
7  &= 1\cdot7+0
\end{align}

So,

\begin{align}
0&=7-7\cdot1=7-7(64-9\cdot7)=7-7\cdot64+49\cdot9=7-7(137-73)+49(73-64)\\
&=7-56\cdot137+105\cdot73.
\end{align}

But this is not in the correct form, the $7$ at the start bothers me and I cant get rid of it without ruining my $137$ or $73$.

How can I fix this?

Comment: $x=137, y=73$ is a nontrivial solution.

Comment: Seems this site is wrong then. https://planetcalc.com/3303/

Comment: So how exactly is this solved then? If I cant get it in the form where I only have multiples of the coefficients?

Comment: That site only seems to find one solution. If there is one solution there are always infinitely many. And if you want $=0$, then $0\cdot 73-0\cdot137=0$ is the most immediate solution and one I should expect such a calculator to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation can be written $73x=137y$. This means that this number is a common multiple of $x$ and $y$, so it is a multiple of their lowest common multiple, which is $73\cdot137$, because $\gcd(73,137)=1$.

Thus there exists $n$ with $73\cdot137n=73x=137y$. Thus $x=137n$, $y=73n$. Conversely, any pair of numbers of this form is a solution.

When you apply the reverse Euclidean algorithm, you don't start from the line with the zero remainder, but from the line with the least nonzero remainder:
\begin{align}
1&=64-9\cdot7\\
&=64-(73-64)\cdot7=73(-7)+64\cdot8\\
&=73(-7)+(137-73)\cdot8\\
&=137\cdot8-73\cdot15
\end{align}

Comment: Ok so now I need to multiply both sides by $0$ thus the trivial solution is $(x^*,y^*)=(0,0)$. For the general solution, I want to use that for a diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ all soluions are given by $$(x,y)=\left(x^*+\frac{b}{gcd(a,b)}n,y^*-\frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}n\right),$$ for some integer $n$. Doing this I get that $$(x,y)=(-137n,-73n).$$ Why are my negative, and yours positive?

Comment: @Parseval Them being positive or negative is *irrelevant*, because $n$ can be positive or negative too.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is slightly off. I know what you're attempting, so I'll show the correct method.

Your $gcd=1$. So we take:

$$1=64-(7\cdot 9)$$
$$=64-7(73-64)=8\cdot 64 -7\cdot 73$$
$$=8(137-73)-7\cdot 73=8\cdot137-15\cdot73$$

There's your first solution.

The rest are given by:

$$(8+73k)\cdot 137 -(15+137k)\cdot 73$$
as this ensures equality is kept.

Comment: I don't see how this is. I think you forget that the equation is equal to $0$ and not $1$.

Comment: Yes. I misread the question, this is the method you were trying to use, but the solutions to your equation are clearly $x=137k, y=73k$ This method is what you use when you are solving $ax+by=gcd(a,b)$

Comment: Well, I wanted to know how to use that method to show that the solutions are those you stated.

Comment: You have $ax-by=0\to ax=by \to x=\frac ba\cdot y$. It suffices that if $y=ak$ then $x=bk$ follows for any integer $k$.